# Raspberry Pi as UPNP Device on Google Home

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, google-home, upnp

I would like to use a **Raspberry Pi** with **NodeJS** as an upnp device, which will be recognized by a standard Google Home device search action. Where can I find any documentation on how a google home discovers devices with upnp?

If there is an ready to use NodeJS library, I would prefer this solution.

Comment: Did you find anything?